# Position image between text for heat legend

Tags: html, css, angular, leaflet

I've got this heat legend:

[image: heat legend]

...but I want the small number to be left to the image, to display a range. Code is as follows:

```
const div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info versuch');
div.innerHTML += `${this.min}&nbsp;<i style="background:linear-gradient(to right, #9bc8f6 0%, #08519c 100%);"></i>&nbsp;${this.max}`;
```

CSS:

```
.info {
 padding: 4px 4px 4px 5px;
 background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.65);
 border-radius: 5px;
}
.versuch {
line-height: 18px;
color: #555;
}

.versuch i {
height: 18px;
width: 200px;
float: left; //image wont show at all if i dont state float
opacity: 1.0;
}
```

Comment: `display:inline-block;`

Comment: tried that, doesn't change anything unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `float` is the culprit though it's doing what would be expected, and it didn't show without it because a `i` as an `inline` element doesn't care about width without content like @IvanSanchez was saying, so change to `inline-block` and remove the `float` and voila. Cheers

```js
// const div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info versuch');
const min = 1234,
      max = 4321;

document.getElementById('blah').innerHTML = `${min}&nbsp;<i style="background:linear-gradient(to right, #9bc8f6 0%, #08519c 100%);"></i>&nbsp;${max}`;
```

```css
.info {
  padding: 4px 4px 4px 5px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.65);
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.versuch {
  line-height: 18px;
  color: #555;
}

.versuch i {
  height: 18px;
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="blah" class="info versuch"></div>
```